# Python Unittest. Testing a method that prints dynamic data

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

I am very new to unittest in python (and testing generally). I have written a simple console application which offers the user multiple options which they can choose by entering a number (1-15), and I have a function that, once the input has been checked, prints a response to screen. In addition to the response changing depending on the users choice, the response is also dependant on data held in text files and as such is subject to change.

How do I go about testing a function like this?

Thanks

Comment: You give it known inputs, and expect a known output. The more things it depends on, the more things you have to provide (although sometimes you can redesign so it doesn't depend on them anymore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical solution is to refactor your function so that

1/ it takes the set of possible outputs as argument instead of reading them from files (or from a database or whatever), and make the caller responsible for passing this argument,

and 2/ it returns a response instead of printing it to stdout, and make the caller responsible for printing to stdout.

Braindead example:

before.py

```
def print_response(choicenum):
    fname = "response-{}.txt".format(choicenum)
    with open(fname) as f:
        data = f.read().splitlines()
    print data[choicenum]


def main():
    choicenum = int(raw_input("choose a number"))
    print_response(choicenum)
```

after.py

```
def get_reponse(choicenum, choices):
    return choices[choicenum]

def read_responses_file(choicenum):
    fname = "response-{}.txt".format(choicenum)
    with open(fname) as f:
        return f.read().splitlines()

def main():
    choicenum = int(raw_input("choose a number"))
    choices = read_responses_file(choicenum)
    print get_response(choicenum, choices)
```

It's still not perfect wrt/ testability (`read_response_file()` still depends on the filesystem - which makes is hardly unittestable - and `main` still prints directly to stdout - which can be tested by mocking `sys.stdout`), but at least the "domain" part (`get_response()`) is decoupled from both the filesystem and stdout.